# server-side languages to create drag and drop website for creating websites

Tags: workflow, server-side, server-side-scripting

What is the technology used behind drag and drop online website builders? They allow you to create a website within a website with zero code. I understand it must contain some advanced server-side scripting techniques, but I am not which one is suitable.

Answer (score 1):

I had done exact same thing before.

All you need is advanced CSS3 and Jquery knowledge to allow user to drag and drop.
After that, you can generate the source code of your web site using server side programming such as php.